# Provisioning Profile for Apple Watch App & Watch Extension

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit, apple-watch, provisioning-profile

Do I need to create separate `bundle identifier` & `provisioning profile` for `Apple watch` and its extension?

i.e My `Host app` identifier now is `com.xxx.myApp` with all capability enabled. So do I need to create two more identifier & profile to run my app in apple watch. ie.`com.xxx.myApp.watchkitapp` & `com.xxx.myApp.watchkitapp.watchkitextension`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you do. Each extension has it´s own project and each project has a `bundle identifier` and `provisioning profile`.

So something like this:

```
com.xxx.myApp.watchkitapp

com.xxx.myApp.watchkitapp.watchkitextension
```

If you add another extension you need to add another `bundle identifier` and `provisioning profile`.

Comment: So is it not required to be same identifier structure as host app identifier? i.e I can create something like com.yyy.mywatchApp.watchkitapp.watchkitextension for extension app.. ?

Comment: **watchOS Apps with Companion iOS App Considerations**
"For watchOS apps that have a companion iOS app in the same project, the embedded WatchKit app and WatchKit extension targets must have the same bundle ID prefix as the iOS app. The WatchKit app must have the format [Bundle ID].watchkitapp, and the WatchKit extension must have the format [Bundle ID].watchkitextension."
Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleidentifier
@nik